# How to handle strange Pandas error "unable to open hashtable..."

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Pandas seems to be calling something I am not asking it to call.. I do not really know. This was working before I re-installed anaconda but now it is not. I reinstalled because my numpy build keeps failing once I close visual studio code (yes I have updated both numpy and pandas)

I am trying to practice cleaning up data. I have already tried re-installing and more. I have tried resetting the index, I have tried ensuring everything sets up as a dataframe but nothing seems to work.

I will try to include a photo of the error but it opens "unable to open 'hashtable_class_helper.pxi': File not found (file:///c:/users/chris/documents/python scripts/pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi)." and asks me to create the file. I am only trying to set the index so that I can work with my data.

my pythonpath is "C:\Users\Chris\Anaconda3\python.exe"
my envionmental path is ;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Users\Chris\Anaconda3\python.exe"

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Chris\Documents\PythonExcel\tb.csv')
dfcases = df[['m04','m514','m014','m1524','m2534','m3544','m4554','m5564','m65','mu','f04','f514','f014','f1524','f2534','f3544','f4554','f5564','f65','fu']].dropna(how='all').fillna(0)
dfcases.set_index('id', inplace=True)
print(dfcases.head())
```

I should expect to see the index labeled as "id"
When I remove the set_index function, it prints the dataframe w/ an index but the index is not labeled

[a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP5Fp.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same "unable to open 'hashtable_class_helper.pxi': File not found" error, but only whenI was catching "Raised Exceptions" while debugging.

Did you maybe check the "Raised Exceptions" box in Visual Studio Code's BREAKPOINTS menu (in the debug tab) too? This means the debugger will also stop on exceptions that are caught and handled by the code (which is useful when you want to debug your own error handling).

If so, you can simply continue the debugger (F5) and eventually your real error will be displayed. Or you can uncheck the "Raised Exceptions" box, and you won't even notice the error occurring.

Answer (score 5):

Your case seems a little than mine, but I had the same popup error come up and I read that it had to do with a keyerror with pandas dataframe. It turned out I was trying to access a dataframe column but lowercase instead of capitalized, so **it was looking for a column name that didn't exist.** I corrected this and the error went away

So, if anyone else gets this issue, check your strings and variable names, syntax, look for keyerrors, use try / except around the issue and print the error

Comment: This was also my situation

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error while debugging on Visual Studio Code and a runtime exception occurred. My Breakpoints configuration was same as yours (in the screenshot).

I 'checked' the 'Raised Exceptions' check box and that stopped the debugger at the line where the exception occurred.